# How to load, access, and use C++ DLL functions in Java?

Tags: java, c++, dll

I have a DLL that I created in C++. It's extremely simple. The DLL is designed to do addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. Here is the code for that:

### Math DLL.cpp

```
#include "Math.h"

using namespace std;

long addition(long a, long b) {
    return a + b;
}

long subtraction(long a, long b) {
    return a - b;
}

long multiplication(long a, long b) {
    return a * b;
}

long division(long a, long b) {
    // Make sure neither variables are 0 to avoid errors
    if (b != 0 && a != 0)
        return a / b;
    else
        return 0;
}

int testReturn() {
    return 7;
}
```

### Math DLL.h

```
#ifdef MATH_EXPORTS
#define MATH_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MATH_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" MATH_API long addition(long a, long b);

extern "C" MATH_API long subtraction(long a, long b);

extern "C" MATH_API long multiplication(long a, long b);

extern "C" MATH_API long division(long a, long b);

extern "C" MATH_API int testReturn();
```

When compiled, this code gives me the files `Math DLL.dll` and `Math DLL.lib`.

I know you can run this in another C++ program like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "tchar.h"

typedef int(__stdcall* importFunction)();

using namespace std;

int main() {
    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(_T("Math DLL.dll"));

    if (hGetProcIDDLL == NULL) {
        cout << "Cannot locate the DLL file." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Found the DLL file!" << endl;
    }

    importFunction testReturn = (importFunction)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "testReturn");
    if (!testReturn) {
        cout << "Could not locate the function" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "testReturn() returned " << testReturn() << endl;
    }

}
```

But how can you do this in Java with Eclipse Photon?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a process, but it seems to work pretty well for me. First, download the JNA library from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/jna/jna-3.1.0.jar.zip). Inside the zip you will find your `.jar` file. Include this in your Java project in Eclipse by right clicking on your project and going to **Build Path > Configure Build Path**.

This should take you to the **Libraries** tab automatically, but if not, click onto it. Then hit the **Add External JARs** button on the right side and locate the JNA `.jar` file.

Now that you have the necessary libraries in your project, create a new class titled "MathDLL". From here, you can input the following code:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

/** Simple example of native library declaration and usage. */
public class MathDLL {
    public interface mathDLL extends Library {
        mathDLL INSTANCE = (mathDLL) Native.loadLibrary("Math DLL", mathDLL.class);

        // Function definition
        long addition(long a, long b);
        long subtraction(long a, long b);
        long multiplication(long a, long b);
        long division(long a, long b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        mathDLL dll = mathDLL.INSTANCE;

        // 500 + 531
        long additionResult = dll.addition(500, 531);
        // 250 - 12
        long subtractionResult = dll.subtraction(250, 12);
        // 12 * 12
        long multiplicationResult = dll.multiplication(12, 12);
        // 400 / 20
        long divisionResult = dll.division(400, 20);

        System.out.println("Addition (should be 1031): " + additionResult + ", Subtraction (should be 238): " + subtractionResult + ", Multiplication (should be 144): " + multiplicationResult + ", Division (should be 20): " + divisionResult);

    }
}
```

This code will add your DLL to your code (make sure your DLL is in the same folder that your Java project runs), define functions, locate them in the DLL during compilation, and allow you to input values and get return values easily in Java!

### Common Mistakes

- Make sure your DLL project matches the same architecture of your system. A x86 computer needs a x86 DLL to run successfully in Java. A x64 computer needs a x64 DLL. Double check that you exported it as the right architecture.
- Don't put `.dll` after the file name in Java. The program knows it's looking for a `.dll` and will return an error if you provide one.
- Make sure your function definitions and parameters always line up with those declared in the actual DLL.

I know I answered my own question, but I hope I helped someone get the answer they were looking for a little easier with less running around.